# Uniqueness of inner product to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Supose $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis of a inner product space $V$. Prove that there exists a unique vector $u$ of $V$ such that $\langle u,v_i\rangle=c_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$ (each $c_i$ is constant).

I'm not sure how to prove this. I tried proving it by contradiction.
Suppose there's $w$ in $V$ such that $\langle w,v_i\rangle=\langle u,v_i\rangle=c_i$ then $\langle w-u,v_i\rangle=0$. But this doesn't get me very far, as it does not imply $w=u$?
How do I prove this? Also, how to prove existence in here?

Comment: I suppose the $c_i$'s are supposed to be fixed?

Comment: Yes, each $c_i$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Correction:
Let $\{e_k\}$ be an orthonormal basis. Expand the $\{e_k\}$ in terms of $\{v_i\}$, 
$$
e_k=\sum_ka_{ki}v_i
$$
Then if $w=\sum_k b_ke_k=\sum_{ki}b_ka_{ki}v_i$ we can find the $b_k$ by solving:
$$
c=A^tb
$$
where $c$ is the vector of $c_i$'s, $A$ the matrix of the coefficients of expansion $a_{ki}$ and $b$ the vector of $b_k$'s

Comment: Yes - you're right. Uniqueness is only for orthonormal basis.

Comment: I corrected it now